# Can PayPal send payment notice to a third party?

Tags: paypal

I'm creating a PayPal Donate button for nonprofit organization, A, that will use another organization B, a 501c3, as its fiscal agent so that donations to A can be tax-exempt. This is a common practice. Is it possible for PayPal to send a notice of the donation to organization A, as well as to organization B, which is the default?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "notice" ?

Comment: I meant the email from PP that the account owner receives when someone makes a payment. Turns out, though, that this is a moot point because of the payment arrangement with the fiscal agent, organization B. Thanks for response, though.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to configure PayPal to send multiple email notifications.

You can use the API payment completion response, or the Webhooks or IPN service, to have your system then send your own emails as a notification.

Alternatively, you can set up simple email forwarding of the payment notification emails sent by PayPal to the primary receiver's account.

Comment: Thank you. The email forwarding is a straightforward solution. Much appreciated, Preston.